# WPF UserControl shows up blank everywhere except in the designer for the control itself

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF UserControl that shows up fine in the designer. However, the UserControl shows up blank anywhere else! What is the cause of this?

The source is here: http://github.com/angelsl/NSMBWSaveEd (the usercontrol is Block2Editor)

Comment: Your project is missing something called MiscUtil so I'm unable to run it.

Comment: Terribly sorry. I have added the DLL and fixed the project file accordingly.

Comment: Hi, can you post URL for the MiscUtil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, god... I finally found it. You have style in Themes\Generic.xaml which sets Template property for your Block2Editor control. Remove it and all be ok.

Comment: That's weird. That file was automatically generated by VS/Blend. Ah well, it works anyway. Thanks.